# Combining jQuery event listeners for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

How can I combine the following into two event listeners?

```
  $(document).on "focus", "input", (e) ->
    $element.addClass "class-name"
  $(document).on "blur", "input", (e) ->
    $element.removeClass "class-name"
  $(document).on "focus", "textarea", (e) ->
    $element.addClass "class-name"
  $(document).on "blur", "textarea", (e) ->
    $element.removeClass "class-name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
 $("textarea").on("blur focus", function(event){
     if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).removeClass("active");
     }
     else {
         $(this).addClass('active');
     } 
 })

 $("input").on("blur focus", function(event){
     if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).removeClass("active");
     }
     else {
         $(this).addClass('active');
     } 
 })
```

Done without a IDE but thats how you combine events. The .on() methods first parameter allows you to list events (Not to sure if it is limited in the amount but I haven't come across any issues as of yet.